# Integral Domain, PID and gcd

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a PID and $R'$ a Integral Domain and $R\subseteq R'$. Let $a,b,d \in R $ and $d$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$ in $R$. Then $d$ is also a gcd of of $a$ and $b$ in $R'$.

Proof:

$d$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$ in $R$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(a,b)=(d)$. It is clear that $d$ is a divisor of of $a$ and $b$ in $R'$, we have to show that it is the Greatest divisor. Let $e\in R'$ be a divisor of $a$ and $b$ in $R'$. This means $\exists \, v,w \in R' \, : a=ve \, , b=we$. Because $(a,b)=(d) $ we can assume $\exists \, s,t\in R' \, : d=sa+tb = sev + tew = esv + etw = e(sv+tw)$ and $sv+tw\in R'$ since $s,t,v,w\in R'$. Let $c:=sv+tw$, then we found a $c\in R'$ with $ce=d$ so $e$ is a divisor of $d$ in $R'$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a few edits to correct typos and confusing notations (be careful: if you use the old-fashioned notation $\left(x\right)$ for the ideal generated by a single element $x$, then you should **not** put extra parentheses around elements when you mean the elements themselves!). Now your proof is correct.

Note that you never use that $R'$ is an integral domain. It is a redundant assumption.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very kind :)